# How to remove a resource without deleting it during a cloudformation stack update

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a cloudformation template that creates an S3 bucket as part of a cloudformation stack. On the new version of my template, I 'm planning to migrate my application from S3 to EFS.

Is there a way to remove the S3 bucket resource from the template, without having it deleted? Ideally, I would like my older users to have the s3 bucket available after they upgrade, but for the new users to not have it at all. It looks like DeletionPolicies could help here, but the documentation on it says that it only applies to stack deletion, but not upgrades.

Answer (score -4, accepted):

When you remove a resource from your template, and update a stack from this template, the resources will be deleted. There is no way to avoid that.

Since your existing users will continue using the S3 bucket, I would recommend preserving the bucket in your template. Remove it when the bucket has been removed from your product completely.

If needed, you could version your template (old vs. new).

If you absolutely need to remove the bucket from your template, you may be able to use a loophole. When CloudFormation deletes a bucket, the bucket must be empty. If it's not empty, then the bucket should be preserved and removed from your stack. You could experiment and see if it works for you. If it works in testing, then you can try using it in production.

Comment: This isn't accurate; you can use a DeletionPolicy attribute on your resource to prevent cloudformation from deleting the resource.

Comment: As the above post is too old (posted in 2017 ) may be that time DeletionPolicy was not available.

Answer (score 47):

Going to elaborate on user3470009's answer.

The [main, advertised purpose](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/delete-cf-stack-retain-resources/) of the `DeletionPolicy` is to keep a resource when a stack is deleted.  It's mentioned almost as an afterthought in the [AWS docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html) for `DeletionPolicy` that it also functions during resource removal from a stack:

> Note that this capability also applies to stack update operations that
>   lead to resources being deleted from stacks. For example, if you
>   remove the resource from the stack template, and then update the stack
>   with the template.

So the workflow to remove a resource from a stack without deleting the actual resource is:

1. Add `"DeletionPolicy" : "Retain"` to the resource declaration in your CF template
2. Apply changes by either saving in the UI or running `aws cloudformation` on the CLI or whatever other tool you use
3. Check in the UI that your resource has the correct changes.  There are some gotchas about when CF doesn't update the metadata.  See the docs link above
4. Remove the resource from your template
5. Apply changes.  Watch the events log to see that it says `DELETE_SKIPPED`:

`2018-10-15T15:32:32.956Z HostedZone DELETE_SKIPPED`

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/refactor-stacks.html

Comment: I've done exactly you described in my production environment and it worked very well. Thanks!

Comment: This is the correct answer. Please update this to be the accepted solution.

Answer (score 6):

Setting a DeletionPolicy of "Retain" will cause the bucket itself to remain after a stack update that deletes the resource.

Comment: I thought that the DeletionPolicy applies when you delete the *stack*, not when you remove a resource from an existing stack template? As per: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-deletionpolicy.html

Answer (score 3):

I came across this question requiring a slight variation.  I needed to extract my bucket to another stack and can not delete it in the move.  This method worked well:

1. create a new stack with the bucket in question.  (note: you now have 2 stacks referencing the same bucket)
2. remove the bucket from the original stack.  The resource is deleted from the original stack but not from S3 since it is still referenced in your new stack.

I also tested Houser's response above and confirmed the bucket will not be deleted if it contains files.  While this works, it does attempt to delete the bucket 3 times before it completes (and reports errors each time).  migrating to a new stack will not throw any errors.